# Visualizing linear mixed model interaction result with continuous variables

Tags: regression, mixed-model, data-visualization, matlab

I have data from 400 participants, each person is in one of the five treatment levels, 80 people per treatment. Within each person I have 5 measurements of my outcome variable. I want to see whether there is a relation between average reaction times and my outcome variable.

I have the following model:

```
dv: dependent variable, continuous

iv_b: independent variable, between-subject, 5 levels, categorical (treatment)

iv_w: independent variable, within-subject, 5 levels, continuous (average reaction time)
```

I used Matlab's fitglme to estimate the following model:

```
'dv ~ 1 + iv_b + iv_w +iv_b*iv_w +(1+iv_w|subject)'
```

Both main effects and interaction effect are highly significant. I'm thinking of visualizing the result to show that the relation between iv_w and dv is different depending on level of iv_b. I'm having trouble finding a good way to do this as both iv_w and dv are on a continuous scale.

My first idea was to take each individual line of best fit between iv_w and dv, superimpose them on each other within one treatment level and then do this for every treatment level (see picture below, for example of one treatment level), but this becomes very crowded and I feel like there is a better way but I'm struggling to find it

[image: Individual regression lines superimposed on top of each other]